# How about Three20 insert to Project

Tags: iphone, interface, build, three20, uitabbar

Hey, everybody.I'm beginning.

I used Xcode + Interface Build to set up a Project on the bases of Tab bar. And now I want to draw support from three20 to realize Tab bar's view, that is to say, when click "item", the view from three20 will display. So I want to know how to insert "Three20 Project" to Tab bar Project?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation: http://github.com/facebook/three20. They have a section 'adding three20 to your project'.

Comment: I have already known the tips you mentioned. Thanks~But maybe misunderstanding here. My question is: I had created two projects by Xcode, one of which is the Tab bar, simply known as Project A; the other is based on the three20, called Project B. Now I hope to embedded Project B into Project A. How to do?